# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: - Changing backslash to forward slash not helping! (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, streamlit

I am working with streamlit to create a tool that takes user input (csv file name) and cleans/produces output as a dataframe. I continuously get OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/'

I am aware of all the past solves of this error, however they all say change backslash to forward slash on windows and this is a quick fix, however after doing this I still have the same issue.

Note my tool still works when inputting the file name, just consistently shows an error (below)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Code:

```
st.header('1 - Express Autocalls')

autocall_gbp_file = str(st.text_input("Please type in your Autocall File Name (GBP)"))

express_gbp = pd.read_csv("M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/" + autocall_gbp_file)
```

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/'
> Traceback:
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site->packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 475, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**)
> File "M:\Desktop\AutomationProject\AutocallApp.py", line 176, in 
> express_gbp = pd.read_csv("M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/" + autocall_gbp_file)
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", >line 311, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", >line 680, in read_csv
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", >line 575, in _read
> parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", >line 933, in **init**
> self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", >line 1217, in _make_engine
> self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
> File "C:\Users\adavie18.conda\envs\projectenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 789, >in get_handle
> handle = open(

Comment: read_csv will expect a csv file, but it looks you are giving it a python file `M:\Desktop\AutomationProject\AutocallApp.py`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry - AutocallApp.py is the name of the file used to run the programme. User input is filename.csv so i am definitely feeding a CSV file. Am I missing something?

Comment: so can you print what are you passing to read_csv? Do something like `filename="M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/" + autocall_gbp_file'` and then do `print(filename)`

Comment: Yeah i can print the filename I am passing through, I am just getting the error on my streamlit page before user input is generated. I have just been attempting to add in try/except to avoid this but still no luck!

Comment: Could it help to use the `os.path` package to handle these? I'm pretty sure it's designed to work across multiple OS'. Try: `import os` and then `path = os.path.join("M:/Desktop/AutomationProject/", autocall_gbp_file)`. If that doesn't work, the error might be in your "M:/Desktop..." string?

Comment: @AlfieDavies Great! I've added an answer now. You can mark it as a solution to close the thread if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual best practice to keep OS paths consistent across platforms in pythong is using the `os` module:

```py
import os

path1 = "Desktop/" + "folder1/" + "folder2/"
with open(path1, "r") as file:
    pass 
    # here, script is not consistent across OS, 
    # and can be difficult to format correctly for Windows


# instead, do:
path2 = os.path.join("Desktop", "folder1", "folder2")
with open(path2, "r") as file:
    pass 
    # now, your script can find your Windows files, 
    # and the same script works for MacOS, Linux platforms
```

This helps keep consistency across platforms, so you can avoid meticulous string formatting